# how to indent a space between image and text in UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitextfield, uikit

I am trying to add a space between the text that user is going to type and an UIImage in a text field . Can any one please help me .

Comment: UIImage in a textfiled? can you provide me a screenshot for what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you talk about [leftView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITextField/leftView) and [rightView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITextField/rightView), you can create subclass of  UITextField and override follow [methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITextField/leftViewRectForBounds:):

```
- (CGRect)leftViewRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds;
- (CGRect)rightViewRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds;
```